# Question about basketball traveling

Tags: rules, basketball

I have a question about the play at 6:46 when Pippen seems to do a little pass to himself:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_tz29TWNdM

Here does it again here at 3:23,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWqspeetGPc

Isn't this traveling? If not, can someone clarify for me traveling rules and how this doesn't break them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that he only takes two steps between him stoping his dribble and him taking a layup. Throwing the ball up and catching it  is only a problem if you travel and Scottie didn’t travel.